# Django Allauth block domain

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am currently working on Google and LinkedIn authentication with Django Allauth on the project.

When a user wants to register via Google or LinkedIn, I need to prevent registration requests with gmail.com and ensure that they only register with business mail. As far as I understand, Allauth cannot provide me with this directly. What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want to blacklist or whitelist some email domains that a user can sign up with?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent users from registering with domains such as gmail.com hotmail.com and return a warning message, but I couldn't find much, I don't know much about it unfortunately...